# Proving the continuity of a function defined by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I need to prove the continuity of a function :

> If $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\phi \leq \psi$, I note
> $$
> \Delta := \bigl\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R} \;:\; 
> x_1 \in [a,b],\, x_2 \in [\phi(x_1),\psi(x_1)] \bigr\}, 
> $$
> $f$ is continuous on $\Delta$, then prove that
> $$
> x_1 \mapsto \int^{\psi(x_1)}_{\phi(x_1)}f(x_1,x_2)\,dx_2
> $$
> is continuous.

Apparently I need to separate the integral and focus on
$$
x_1 \mapsto \int^{\psi(x_1)}_zf(x_1,x_2)\,dx_2
$$
then use Heine theorem but I am stuck with
\begin{multline} 
\forall x_1 \in [a,b],\, \forall \gamma>0,\, \exists \alpha > 0,\, \forall \varepsilon > 0,\, |h| < \alpha \\ 
\implies \left| \int^{\psi(x_1)}_z f(x_1+h,x_2)\, dx_2 
- \int^{\psi(x_1)}_z f(x_1,x_2)\, dx_2 \right| 
< \varepsilon \bigl( \psi(x_1) - z \bigr)
\end{multline}

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, good first question. By "Heine Theorem" I presume you mean Heine-Borel, i.e., continuous functions send compact sets to compact sets?

Comment: Composition of continuous functions (and difference of two continuous functions)  is continuous.

Comment: The use of $x$ as a free variable and a bound variable inside the integration cannot end well.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thak you ! yes, I mean the Heine-Borel theorem, this is how I got the $\varepsilon$

Comment: @geetha290krm I don't see the composition

Comment: One approach would be to smplify and consider the change of variable $t = \phi(x) + s(\psi(x)-\phi(x))$. This way the integration is over a fixed interval.

Comment: Please fix the variable issue before I have a cardiac event.

Comment: @copper.hat I am sorry, I don't understand how to do this change of variable and wouldn't I need $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be differentiable?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Sorryyy I meant No, it is the Heine-Cantor theorem

Comment: No, this is why I wanted you to fix the variable issue first. If you fix $x$ you can reparameterise the integral. Of course, now you need to deal with the two variable function $(x,s) \mapsto f(\phi(x) + s(\psi(x)-\phi(x)))$, but the bounds are fixed to $0,1$. No free lunch, unfortunately,

Comment: @copper.hat what variable issue? Did I miss something?

Comment: @copper.hat ah yes sorry wait there is an explanation

Comment: Yes, read my first comment. Some kind soul has addressed the issue.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay I fixed it, I thought I wanted to simplify the question but yeah...

Comment: Sorry everyone for the error, I fixed it

Comment: @copper.hat would you mind taking a look at it now? My first input was wrong